# How to input hex values instead of chars as input for boost::asio::buffer

Tags: c++, c, char, boost-asio, cin

I have trouble to find a good solution for the following scenario:

A *write* function takes a *const char*, which is given as an user-input through *cin.get(ch)* by calling *write(ch)*. ch is a *char*.

```
while (c.active()) 
{
 char ch;
 cin.get(ch); // blocking wait for standard input

 if (ch == 3) // ctrl-C to end program
   break;
 c.write(ch);
}
```

This works fine, but I would like to modify it, so that it is possible to make an input like: "0A00CD88" or "0A 00 CD 88" and use it as input for *write*, which is using it as input for *boost::asio::buffer*.

In order to do so, I can use **C/C++** and **boost**.

Thanks to anyone who shares knowledge on this matter!

Comment: To be more specific: "0A 00 CD 88" is a command I need to send as such. So I have to be able to put in "0A00CD88" or with spaces - i don't care really - but it has to transform into a stream of chars of according value to 0A,00,CD,88. I am sorry, this was not that clear in my initial question.

@denys: thanks - your solution helped and directed me to an improvement of my question

Comment: I found a similar example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221170/how-to-turn-a-hex-string-into-an-unsigned-char-array), but I am a bit slow today - still trying to adapt this somehow, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[That is your solution:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3221193/658346)

just replace

```
std::string hex_chars("E8 48 D8 FF FF 8B 0D");
```

with

```
std::string hex_chars;
std::getline(std::cin, hex_chars);
```

P.S. I hope I've understood your question correctly :)

Comment: I am still about to understand how it all works, but it works as I asked for it to work - only instead of bytes.push_back(c) I am using c.write(ch). Thank you denys, James McNellis and Gbps!

Answer (score 2):

Next code will solve your 1st scenario (without spaces)

```
int x;
std::cin >> std::hex >> x;
```

[Use hexadecimal base](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/hex/)