# Convert string of hex to char array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11

I have a string that represents an hexadecimal number:

```
std::string hex = "3371";
```

I want to convert it to a char array:

```
char hex[2] {0x33, 0x71};
```

Is there any convenient way to do it? I can use c++11 features, if it may help.

Motivation:
I need to save an integer (4 bytes), using 2 bytes char array.
The way how I thought it can be done is to convert it to string using std::hex, and then convert the string to the char array, but this is the point where I cannot continue..
If there is another simple way - I would like to hear :)

Important: I can assume that the hex number is less than 0xFFFF, and a positive number.

Comment: How to turn a hex string into an unsigned char array?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221170/how-to-turn-a-hex-string-into-an-unsigned-char-array

Comment: Use `std::istringstream` and `std::hex`.

Comment: That C answer is not a duplicate. There is scope for an elegant C++11 solution.

Comment: "I need to save an integer (4 bytes), using 2 bytes char array" So you want to put 4 bytes into 2? You want to compress the data? Or do you mean 4 decimal digits?

Comment: convert it to int, and do some bit operations.

Comment: @KarstenKoop - I said that the number is less than 0xFFFF, so basically it is short (2 bytes) to char[2] (2 bytes).

Answer (score 4):

Just use [std::stoi()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
std::string hex = "3371";
uint16_t num = std::stoi( hex, nullptr, 16 );
uint8_t array[sizeof(num)];
memcpy( array, &num, sizeof( num ) );
```

note order of bytes will depend of endianness of your platform. If you need network order (as shown on your example)  use `htons()` function:

```
uint16_t num = htons( std::stoi( hex, nullptr, 16 ) );
```

Comment: Nice!
and if I want to do the same, but with long? (i.e. save long number on char array with size 4)?

Comment: Then use `std::stol()` and `htonl()`

Answer (score -1):

I found out a better way to convert a number to char array, as I needed. This solution works only for unsigned types!

```
template <typename T> bool ToByteArray(T num, unsigned char* ret, size_t size) {
  if (ret == nullptr) {
      std::cout << "Error in: " << __func__ << ": nullptr" << std::endl;
      return false;
  }
  // drop the right-most bytes and convert to new right most byte.
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      ret[i] = (int)((num >> (24 - 8*i)) & 0xFF);
  }
  return true;
}
```

This is more elegant way to do it.

If you want to convert it back - you might use:

```
long FormatBlock(const unsigned char* arr, size_t size) {
  long num = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      num += ((long)arr[i] << (24 - i*8));
  }
  return num;
}
```

Comment: This is really not more elegant. It does not use C++11 features (as requested in the question), it uses old C-style character arrays and pointers. Despite using a template (why?), this looks more like C code.

Comment: 1. template is there because I wan't this function to work with every type (int, short, long, etc).
2. I agree that this is a c code, but I prefer using it because it is generic for every type. The solution which Slava gave works only for integer.

Comment: Using c++11 features is not a must. If there is a better way to solve the problem - it doesn't matter if c++11 features are in use or not

Comment: "I wan't this function to work with every type (int, short, long, etc)." you will get surprises with negative values.

Comment: OK, I will add: unsigned values (I will not have data with negative values)