# Arduino: Convert string array to byte array

Tags: arrays, string, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I am working on a project where I first need to build up the payload as a string then later on convert it to byte when sending the payload. I am having issues with conversion.

*Reson why payload build-up is in string is due to the way it generates each single string, "02", "12", "31", "03" and "36" are the result after diffrent methods of calculations.*

```
String lockHexString[5];  
lockHexString[0] = "02"; 
lockHexString[1] = "12"; 
lockHexString[2] = "31"; 
lockHexString[3] = "03"; 
lockHexString[4] = "36"
```

Now when I have **lockHexString**, I need convert the lockHexString to byteArray, so It looks like

```
byte lockByte[5] = {0x02, 0x12, 0x31, 0x03, 0x36};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string of hex to char array c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47204749/convert-string-of-hex-to-char-array-c)

Comment: @kaylum Those answers are useless on the system having 2kB of RAM. No std at all.

Comment: @0___________ I probably should have linked directly to the answer that that post is duplicated to. It has an answer without `std`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261798/converting-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array

Comment: no sorry, that method takes too much memory, as I only have 2kb.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use the String to create the payload to begin with. If you use `char*` strings, then `atoi()` would be a simple solution. or Maybe if you could store your string as decString instead of hexString, then at least you could easily convert it to a byte with `(uint8_t) String.toInt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are always 2 chars I would not use heavy standard functions on Arduino. Simple:

```
unsigned getdigit(const char ch)
{
    switch(ch)
    {
        case '0' ... '9':
          return ch - '0';
        case 'a' ... 'f':
          return ch - 'a';
        case 'A' ... 'F':
          return ch - 'A';
        default:
          return 0;
    }
}
unsigned char convHEX(const char *str)
{
    return getdigit(str[0]) * 16 + getdigit(str[1]);
}
```