# c++ hex set of strings to array of bytes not return vector

Tags: c++, design-patterns, hex, byte

So basically , I want to create a function that

takes this hex pattern:

```
"03 C6 8F E2 18 CA 8C E2 94 FD BC E5 03 C6 8F E2"
```

and returns this array of bytes:

```
BYTE pattern[] = { 0x03, 0xC6, 0x8F, 0xE2, 0x18, 0xCA, 0x8C, 0xE2, 0x94, 0xFD, 0xBC, 0xE5, 0x03, 0xC6, 0x8F, 0xE2 };
```

My main problem is what i need like each 0x03 in one byte cell, of the output array exactly as i described,

if i use this

```
   #include <windows.h>

    std::vector<BYTE> strPatternToByte(const char* pattern, std::vector<BYTE> bytes)
    {
        std::stringstream converter;
    
        std::istringstream ss( pattern );
        std::string word;
        while( ss >> word )
        {
            BYTE temp;
            converter << std::hex << "0x" + word;
            converter >> temp;
    
            bytes.push_back( temp );
        }
    
        return bytes;
    }
    
        int main()
        {
    
            const char* pattern = "03 C6 8F E2 18 CA 8C E2 D4 FD BC E5 03 C6 8F E2";
            std::vector<BYTE> bytes;
            bytes = strPatternToByte(pattern,bytes);
            BYTE somePtr[16];
            for ( int i=0 ; i < 16 ; i++)
            {
                somePtr[i] = bytes[i];
            }
    
    
            for(unsigned char i : somePtr)
            {
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
            }
            /*
             * output should be:
              0x03
              0xC6
              0x8F
             * etc
             * .
             * .
             */
    
            return 0;
    }
```

it doesn't actually do what i need because when i debug it , i look at the bytes vector and i see it puts 0 in a cell, x in a cell , 0 , in cell , 3 in cell , which is not what i want,  is there anyway to solve this kind of problem ?
the output aint like it should be, I added what the output should be there in the code something like this:

```
        /*
     * output should be:
      0x03
      0xC6
      0x8F
     * etc
     * .
     * .
     */
```

the somePtr array is my last output should be, with as i described up.

thanks.

Comment: What is `BYTE`?

Comment: I think BYTE is of size 8-bits. It needs to be at least 16-bits.

Comment: Its 8 bits as Harry said  I guess..

Comment: instead of BYTE, use uint16_t datatype.

Comment: In the vector? or in the array aswell?

Comment: thing is , i need it as BYTE, like the array output i described it has to be like that as I use it for something else after.

Comment: _Its 8 bits as Harry said I guess_ .. What does this mean? What have you defined `BYTE` to be? There is no data type with that name in standard C++. Is there any specific header which you have included to get `BYTE` type?

Comment: there is.. its just BYTE from #include <windows.h>

Comment: Instead of guessing what `BYTE` is, try making a [mre]

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3221170/1216776

Comment: @J.Steve `<windows.h>` is not standard c++. There's no indication in the question that this header is being used.

Comment: Well sorry, didn't notice that will indicate in next questions and will edit my post

Comment: no these doesn't answer my question, that is output unsigned char array, my main purpose is to return BYTE array @stark this is not duplicate.

Comment: @molbdnilo changing BYTE temp to int temp doesn't solve anything..

Comment: @MarekR no it doesn't

Comment: Can you guys read at least what im requesting before posting random answers and saying duplicate or different outputs, this aint no race..

Comment: Have you actually tried the solutions people have given you? Because when I look in the [Windows API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) it says: BYTE - This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:
`typedef unsigned char BYTE;`  So, it seems a bit odd that a solution that gives `unsigned char` don't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of minor errors.

By reusing your `converter` object it no longer works after the first conversion because it gets into an error state. Try this version that recreates the `stringstream` each time round the loop (you could also call `converter.clear();` at the end of the loop).

```
while (ss >> word)
{
    int temp;
    std::stringstream converter;
    converter << std::hex << "0x" + word;
    converter >> temp;
    bytes.push_back(temp);
}
```

Also `temp` should be an `int` (you are reading integers after all).

The output loop is wrong, try this

```
 for (int i : somePtr)
 {
     std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << i << std::endl;
 }
```

Again note that `i` is an `int`, and I've added formatting to get the effect you wanted. You will need to `#include <iomanip>`

Comment: Thank you now i understand what was wrong, this is actually the correct solution worked well for me. good job

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::vector<uint8_t> bytesFromHex(std::basic_istream<T>& stream, size_t reserve = 0x100)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> result;
    result.reserve(reserve);
    auto flags = stream.flags();
    stream.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<unsigned>{stream}, {}, std::back_inserter(result));
    stream.flags(flags);
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<uint8_t> bytesFromHex(std::basic_string_view<T> s, size_t reserve = 0x100)
{
    std::basic_istringstream<T> stream{std::basic_string<T>{s}};
    return bytesFromHex(stream, reserve);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/aW915b

Comment: Doesn't give the same output as im asking for..
and giving error on the basic_string_view part aswell

Comment: I used C++17, but it is easy to tweak this to older version (trash string_view). Anyway use godbolt to show what is your issue, on my example it works like charm.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/a1Wen4

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned char BYTE; // Remove this line if you've included windows.h

std::vector<BYTE> strPatternToByte(std::string hex_chars) {
    std::istringstream hex_chars_stream(hex_chars);
    std::vector<BYTE> bytes;
    unsigned c;
    hex_chars_stream >> std::hex;
    while (hex_chars_stream >> c) bytes.push_back(c);
    return bytes;
}

int main() {
    std::string hex_chars = "03 C6 8F E2 18 CA 8C E2 D4 FD BC E5 03 C6 8F E2";
    auto bytes = strPatternToByte(hex_chars);
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << std::uppercase;
    for (unsigned i : bytes) std::cout << "0x" << std::setw(2) << i << '\n';
}
```

[**Output** :](https://wandbox.org/permlink/y1D9SdMw17gppa20)

```
0x03
0xC6
0x8F
0xE2
0x18
0xCA
0x8C
0xE2
0xD4
0xFD
0xBC
0xE5
0x03
0xC6
0x8F
0xE2
```

Comment: You put the 0x in the cout at main, i need that to be in the actual byte array like i asked in the output up, and the vector bytes here u return is not like what i asked, it has integers, not 0x03, 0xC6 actually but u added them in the main..

Comment: @J.Steve You cannot have `0x03` in the returned vector. In it each element is of 1 byte. With 1 byte it is impossible to store `0x03` in formatted form it will be stored internally as just `3`, similarly `0xC6` will just be `198` in the vector.